# Recover POST data from Apache logs?

Tags: apache-2.2, logging

I've just noticed our website's contact form is broken. I don't know how long it has been so and I might have missed important emails. Would it be possible to recover POST data from Apache's logs ?

**EDIT**: False alarm... My Google Apps account was messed up. Nonetheless it would be interesting to get an answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, only GET querystrings are included in the log files. Otherwise the log files would be way too massive, especially when uploading BLOBs (file uploads).

Answer (score 2):

According to [this link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apache-mod_dumpio-log-post-data/) it can be done with the [mod_dumpio](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dumpio.html) module.

I think it would probably make more sense to put it in the web application itself though.

Comment: But you would have had to enable this prior to the incident.